# Cursor position in VIM abbreviation

Tags: vim

is there some way to tell VIM place the cursor at some position after abbreviation expansion?
Say you have something like this in .gvimrc

```
iabberv <? <?=|?>
```

and you want to place cursor where pipe character is automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick solution that I'd use in this case is to insert some key presses to the abbreviation:

```
iabbrev <? <?=?><Left><Left>
```

Would place the cursor two places left, after the `=`.

In this manner, you can use various movement keys such as `<End>`, `<Home>`, or even return to normal mode with `<Esc>` and command usual normal-mode commands. The example would then be

```
iabbrev <? <?=?><Esc>hha
```

and it does the same as the first example. If you expand an abbreviation with space, it will have one extra space. <strike>which you can get rid of by using a `<BS>` (backspace) in the abbreviation.</strike> Or expand with `<C-]>` which will leave no space.

Correction: since the abbreviation is first expanded, and after that the space inserted, you need a small function found in the help (map.txt):

```
func Eatchar(pat)
   let c = nr2char(getchar(0))       
   return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c      
endfunc
```

This is best put in `.vimrc`. Now the following abbreviation will work fully as intented:

```
:iabbrev <silent> <? <?=?><Left><Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```

It is a bit messy, but has an external function call that removes the white space and it should work well.

Comment: I tried  
iabbrev <? <?=?><Esc>hha<bs>  
but it deletes "=" character :) where should I place <bs> ?  
It is exactly what I want, except this <bs> problem.

Comment: Really sorry for not testing the `<BS> ` functionality before answering. I edited in a suitable workaround.

Comment: Cool, it works, accepting this answer :) I'm using it like this:
`iabbrev <? <?=$?><Esc>hha<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>`

Comment: Just wanna add that `Eatchar`'s help entry could be found using `:helpgrep Eatchar`.

Comment: How does this function work? I tried a simple function with a command `norm X` and I could not get it to delete the char after expansion.

Answer (score 5):

What you want are snippets. I use snipmate for that.

Comment: You should take a look on [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), it's just awesome!

Comment: Please Daenyth, could you improve a little bit your answer by providing some link? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [lh-map-tools](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_VimL_library):

```
"
" in {rtp}/ftpluvin/vim/vim_snippets.vim
inoreab  <buffer> <silent> if    
      \ <C-R>=InsertSeq('if', 'if!cursorhere!\nendif!mark!')<CR>
```

Other plugins offer a similar feature.